# Python extract 3 integers from string

Tags: python, string, beautifulsoup, integer

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
URL = "https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/"
r = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')
countHTML = soup.find('div', attrs = {'class':'content-inner'})

for countVar in countHTML.findAll('div', attrs = {'class':'maincounter-number'}):
    count = countVar.span
```

Right now variable `count` returns:

```
<span style="color:#aaa">270,069</span>
<span>11,271</span>
<span>90,603</span>
```

I need help on extracting 3 separate integers from this string, I have tried `count[0]` but this is not an array so it does not work.

```
String1 = "270,069"
String2 = "11,271"
String3 = "90,603"
```

Then converts into 3 integers by removing the comma

```
Int1 = 270069
Int2 = 11271
Int3 = 90603
```

Perhaps Regex will help?

Edit:

I currently have `numbers = []` as one value in a list, such as

```
numbers = """
270069
11271
90603"""
```

so if I do numbers[0], all 3 integers will show up as 1 value, how do I strip new lines, and make them into a list or array with 3 separate values?

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: hi there good day dear Andrew - i get back the following result: 

`
    
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/atom_script_tempfiles/0c9e3b30-6d27-11ea-84a4-095d4171334a", line 2, in <module>
    worldometers.info
NameError: name 'worldometers' is not defined
[Finished in 0.069s]`

 i am on MX-Linux on Atom and i do not know why i get this back!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could usse:

```
my_numbers = []
for countVar in countHTML.findAll('div', attrs = {'class':'maincounter-number'}):
    my_numbers.append(int(countVar.span.text.strip().replace(',', '')))

print(my_numbers)
```

output:

```
[270104, 11272, 90603]
```

Comment: It kind of works, but it returns all 3 integers as 1 value in the list, how do I get 3 separate ones? Thanks

Comment: look at the output, where do you see 1 value? you can use: `my_numbers[0]` if you want to access the first one, for example :)

Comment: Turns I was printing it in the for loop, that was my bad, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Yep, some simple Regex should work.

```
s = '''<span style="color:#aaa">270,069</span>
<span>11,271</span>
<span>90,603</span>'''

num_strs = re.findall('[0-9,]+', s)

numbers = [int(ns.replace(',', '')) for ns in num_strs]

# Extract to variables
num1, num2, num3 = numbers
```

Comment: This helps, but the result returns all 3 integers as 1 array, how do I extract them into 3 separate integers, I've tried numbers[0], but it is an array with only 1 value, so it still gives 3 combined integers in one. How do you split '\n' and transfer it into a new int or string? Sorry I'm new

Comment: This is a ValueError, since numbers only have one value. The error code is `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the split method as follows

```
intAsString = '123\n1234\n12345'
listOfInts = intAsString.split('\n')
```

Here, listOfInts would be `['123', '1234', '12345']`

In python, \n is the new line character, so splitting by newline should give you the three numbers